# How to pass array of Object parameter to Alamofire swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm new In Swift anyone help me.

I want to pass array of object to Alamofire and I don't know how to do that

Here is the parameter that required:

```
{
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ZWU4OGZiNzhiYTBkMjMyZDFmYWZkMzgiLCJpYXQiOjE1OTIyOTk2Njh9.AVuxiTZy10fV2ZMZcT-oHXSg6PdK3tfE",
    "zipCodes": [
        {
            "zip_code": "55001",
            "city": "Afton",
            "state": "MN",
            "county": "Washington"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I do that

```
 let parameters : [String : String] = ["token" : retrivedToken, "zipCodes" : [{
            "zip_code": "55001",
            "city": "Afton",
            "state": "MN",
            "county": "Washington"
            }]
        ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let bodyParams: [String : Any] = [
            "token": "\(retrivedToken)",
            "zipCodes":[
                "county": "Washington",
                "state": "MN",
                "zip_code": "55001",
                "city": "Afton"
            ]
        ]
    }
```

let urlString = "abc.com"

```
Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: bodyParams ,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {  
response in
  switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    print(response)
                    break
                case .failure(let error):

                 print(error)
      }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this answer? This is the same like what i wrote earlier.

Comment: From [Documentations](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#making-requests): **"There are additional methods that allow you to make requests using Parameters dictionaries and ParameterEncoding types. This API is no longer recommended and will eventually be deprecated and removed from Alamofire."** It will be removed so how it will be done after that?

Answer (score 2):

Simply just use your parameter to your request.

```
func sendRequestRequest() {
// JSON Body
let parameters: [String : Any] = [
    "token": retrivedToken,
    "zipCodes": [
        "county": "Washington",
        "state": "MN",
        "zip_code": "55001",
        "city": "Afton"
    ]
]

// Fetch Request
Alamofire.request("your API url", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
    .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
    .responseJSON { response in
        if (response.result.error == nil) {
            print("HTTP Response Body: \(response.data)")
        }
        else {
            print("HTTP Request failed: \(response.result.error)")
        }
    }
```

}

Dont forget, if you use Alamofire v5, use `AF.request` instead of `Alamofire.request`

Comment: From [Documentations](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#making-requests): **"There are additional methods that allow you to make requests using Parameters dictionaries and ParameterEncoding types. This API is no longer recommended and will eventually be deprecated and removed from Alamofire."** It will be removed so how it will be done after that?